# What is the difference between super and this in terms of inheritence?

Tags: java

Here is my question, `super` keyword is used only in case of inheritence ?
In terms of inheritence, what is the difference between `this` and `super`?

Comment: Did you read the [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/inheritance.html) [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- `this` refers to the current *object*, i.e. it's a reference
- `super` refers to the *super class*, i.e. it's a scoping mechanism

The current object is **the same object** as the object of the superclass. If you have a `Dog` that extends `Animal`, and do `new Dog()` then you create **1** object, and this object is both the `Animal` instance and the `Dog` instance.

Here's an example

```
class Dog extends Animal {

    public void treatWell(DogSpa spa) {
        spa.takeCareOf(this);      // pass this object to the spa
    }

    public void makeSound() {
        System.out.println("bark");
        super.makeSound();         // call makeSound in Animal scope
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this refers to current object, while super refers to current object's parent class.

Consider this:

```
class Parent {
    protected int value;
    public void test() {
         //print parent
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public void test() {
       //print child
    }
    private void someMethod() {
        this.test();//will print child
        super.test();//will print parent
    }        
}
```

Comment: I just gave example for understanding purpose. I am not diving into why inheritance or composition etc.